# Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, npm, electron

I am making a electron app that uses firebase's realtime database. I've followed a tutorial from youtube and read the docs from firebase's site. All done perfectly.
My code:
main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <!-- https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#csp-meta-tag -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
    Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
    and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
  </body>
  <script>
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('main.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

renderer.js (from the tutorial)

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "***",
    authDomain: "***",
    databaseURL: "***",
    projectId: "***",
    storageBucket: "***",
    messagingSenderId: "***",
    appId: "***",
    measurementId: "***"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

NOTE!! I used `***` to replace the data just to be sure they are not exposed in anyway. My program has them as they should be.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rubik",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/grpc-js": "^0.7.4",
    "firebase": "^7.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: electron-v8.2-win32-x64-unknown
Found: [node-v72-win32-x64-unknown]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\electron-v8.2-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\src\client_interceptors.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\src\client.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\index.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\firebase\dist\index.node.cjs.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\renderer.js
- C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\main.html
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rubik\node_modules\grpc\src\grpc_extension.js:64)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:728)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74)
```

I've tried everything on the internet related to this error.
I've reinstalled nodejs and npm with folder removal and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether gRPC *can* be used in an Electron app, but would suggest taking another way out. Right now you're loading the SDKs for all Firebase products into your app, which is probably *much* more than needed. Not only does that inflate the size of your app, it also introduces all kind of unnecessary dependencies like gRPC (which is only used by Firestore).

The simplest way to both reduce the size of the app, and get rid of the error message, is to only include the Firebase SDKs you're actually using:

```
var firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/database")
```

For more on this, see the <kbd>Node.js</kbd> tab in the [add Firebase SDKs and initialize Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) section in the Firebase documentation. Even if you're not using Node.js directly, you'll want to look here for the samples using the `require` method of importing modules.